# How to generate auto increment values in Cassandra from Spark using Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I need to generate auto increment id in a column in sequence manner in Cassandra from Spark using Java.

Can somebody help on this?

Comment: If you mean a column with an id incremented for each row inserted like mysql (and others) do, i am afraid this feature is not available in Cassandra.

Comment: I mean the same.... Thanks. So is there any other way to do it?

Comment: If you need a unique value, I recommend using a uuid or timeuuid field. You can populate the later with the now() value.

Comment: would it be in a sequence?  @medvekoma

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we use Cassandra NoSQL counter or LWT for auto incremental integer key generation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987216/should-we-use-cassandra-nosql-counter-or-lwt-for-auto-incremental-integer-key-ge)

Comment: @Aman, yes, the now() function returns a timeuuid, which is a unique timestamp.