# How to generate a Business sequence number in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

There is plenty of information around which provides ways in which to generate ***uuid*** based representations of data stored in C*. Usually, these serve well as **surrogate** keys.

We are moving from the SQL to NoSQL (C* to be more specific). One of  the important things for us to ponder about is how are we going to maintain existing Oracle/DB2 sequence generators in C* which is used for **business** data.

Roughly, these sequence generators which are used to identify business data e.g., an *order number* etc. will need to be both idempotent and work well in a distributed system like C* which is known to honor only 1 of the 3 CAP attributes.

AFAIK C* [counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987216/should-we-use-cassandra-nosql-counter-or-lwt-for-auto-incremental-integer-key-ge) are not idempotent. Naively trying to implement the Oracle 
`nextval` function (e.g.,

```
start with 1000008
increment by 1
maxvalue 1000000000
```

)

in C* will lead to some [challenges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935915/how-to-create-auto-increment-ids-in-cassandra?rq=1) both in terms of implementation and designing for this to be resilient to failure.

We can't wait for C*3.x and are currently on 2.2.x and are looking for options.

TIA.

Comment: Convert all your existing id to Time UUID and generate Time UUID using UUIDs class

Comment: +1 to using timeuuids, you get an order and uniqueness without a very complex distributed systems problem.